# open socket with arguments

Tags: c, sockets, arguments, winsock2

Hello i try to open socket with arguments (you know argv and argc) but for some reason the program shows that error WSAStratup @ 8 and some things like that. 
I think the problem is related to the income of the arguments.

I would be happy if you can see and help me understand why this is happening thanks.

My code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
WSADATA info;
int err, s, cResult;
char ch[10] = "";
char cl[10] = "";

strcpy(ch, argv[3]);



err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &info);
if (err != 0)
{
 printf("WSAtartup faild\n");
 return(1);
}

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
 printf("Error creating = %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
else
{
 printf("socket function succeeded\n");
}

SOCKADDR_IN clientService;
clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
clientService.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));

cResult = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *) &clientService, sizeof (clientService));
if (cResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
 printf("connect failed error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
}

send(s, ch, 10, 0);
recv(s, cl, 10, 0);

puts(ch);
puts(cl);
if (strcmp(ch, cl) == 0)
{
 printf(" Same\n");
}
else
{
 printf("Not same\n");
}


cResult = closesocket(s);
if (cResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
 printf("closesocket function failed error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
 WSACleanup();
 return 1;
}

system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question what is failing, but to correctly initialize Winsock 2 supported functions, you want to call

```
WSAStartup(WINSOCK_VERSION, &wsadata);
```

Where WINSOCK_VERSION is defined in Winsock2.h as:

```
#define WINSOCK_VERSION MAKEWORD(2,2)
```

You'll also want to link with ws2_32.lib to use Winsock 2 functions (Winsock 1.1 is really old - that version is exported from wsock32.lib).

Comment: From what the OP is asking, it sounds like a linker error to me, so +1 for mentioning ws2_32.lib.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran your program in my Visual studio and it runs fine. You should take into account several things: when calling your program you should specified an IP, port number and some test message.

`myprogram 127.0.0.1 1024 "test message"`

Also, you should check every socket command, like `send()` and `recv()` if they execute or give an error. See the modified program. And finally you should link your program with the `wsock32.lib` library. Go to *Project properties* and add this library to the *Additional dependencies* in the *Linker* page, depends on your language, I have in Spanish and it says "*Dependencias adicionales*" maybe your Visual Studio says something different.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA info;
    int err, s, cResult;
    char ch[10] = "";
    char cl[10] = "";

    // Check that the appropiate arguments has been given
    if (argc < 4) return -1;

    // Copy up the size of ch
    strncpy(ch, argv[3], sizeof(ch));

    err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &info);
    if (err != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAtartup failed: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        system("PAUSE");
        return -1;
    }

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Error creating = %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        system("PAUSE");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("socket function succeeded\n");
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
    clientService.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));

    cResult = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *) &clientService, sizeof (clientService));
    if (cResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("connect failed error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        system("PAUSE");
        return -1;
    }

    if (send(s, ch, 10, 0) > 0)
    {
        puts(ch);
        if (recv(s, cl, 10, 0) > 0)
        {
            puts(cl);
            if (strcmp(ch, cl) == 0)
            {
                printf(" Same\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Not same\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("error in recv() %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("error in send() %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    cResult = closesocket(s);
    if (cResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("closesocket function failed error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    WSACleanup();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```